# How to format an empty (NDEFFormatable) NFC Tag in iOS

Tags: ios, nfc, core-nfc

I'm currently working with some NFC Tags and iOS 13.

One problem is, that some of my NFC tags are delivered as `NDEFFormatable`. I know that I have to format the tag first to work with NDEF. I can do that with an 3rd party Android app. But how can I do that with my own iOS App?
Currently the tag is recognized as 'ISO15693' tag and the result of the queryNDEFStatus method is `.notSupported`.

I have also tried to write an empoty message to that NFC tag but iOS is responding with an error "NDEF tag is read only"

As I know you like to have some code here are the important parts:

```
session = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693], delegate: self)
    session?.alertMessage = "Bitte halten Sie das Gerät an den zu scannenden NFC Tag"
    session?.begin()
```

...

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {

    if tags.count > 1 {
        // Restart polling in 500ms
        let retryInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(500)
        session.alertMessage = "Mehr als 1 NFC Tag gefunden. Bitte scannen Sie jeden Tag einzeln."
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + retryInterval, execute: {
            session.restartPolling()
        })
        return
    }

    let tag = tags.first!

    // Connect to the found tag and perform NDEF message reading
    session.connect(to: tag) { (error: Error?) in

        if nil != error {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: "NFC Tag konnte nicht gelesen werden")
            return
        }

        if case let NFCTag.iso15693(iso15693Tag) = tag{

            iso15693Tag.queryNDEFStatus(completionHandler: { (ndefStatus: NFCNDEFStatus, capacity: Int, error: Error?) in

                guard error == nil else {
                    session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Status des Tags konnte nicht gelesen werden")
                    return
                }

                switch ndefStatus {
                case .notSupported:

                    //NDFEFFormatable tag is handled here !!!!

                    session.alertMessage = "Der Tag unterstützt das NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF) nicht!"
                    session.invalidate()
                case .readOnly:
                    //read tag
                case .readWrite:
                     //read or write tag
                @unknown default:
                    session.alertMessage = "Unbekannter Status"
                    session.invalidate()
                }
            })
        } else if case let NFCTag.miFare(miFareTag) = tag { //check if we have a MiFare Tag
            //other type of tags

        } else {
            session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Dieser Tag wird aktuell leider nicht unterstützt")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any success with that?

Answer (score 1):

Some sources say that iOS can only work with already formatted cards

https://help.gototags.com/article/nfc-tag-encoding-iphone/

But you might be able to go to low level commands to write the correct blocks to format the card yourself.

You don't specify the type of card, so assuming it's a type 2 the http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf  (If not the other specs are at http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/ )

But possibly more like a Type 5 Card which I don't have access to the Specs of, but something similar could be done for Type 5 as Type 2 (You could use various android App's like NXP's Taginfo App to compare a formatted NDEF type V tag with a non formatted one to see if it is blocks 3 and 4 on type V cards as well)

But for Type 2

Section 6.4.1 shows how it detects that it is a NDEF formated card.

For Type 2 cards Block 03 has to have the NDEF capability container of 4 bytes, A lot of cards have this preset from the Factory, if not you need to write the 4 byte capability container to block 03.

The container format is in the spec's but below is a summary:-

Byte 0 = E1h indicates that NDEF data is present inside the tag

Byte 1 = 10h indicates support for version 1.0 (major number 1h, minor number 0h) of the mapping document (i.e., the version of this specification). - Version 1.0 is the latest version I believe.

Byte 2 = Size of the data area, so card specific value but the value is the data area size divided by 8 and represented in hex. e.g. 128 bytes of data storage are indicated value equal to 10h

Byte 3 = Is about security and value 0h indicates write access granted without any security

---

Then you need to format the card with a blank TLV message to block 4 to format the card.

A blank TLV message in block 4 is

Byte 0 = 03h

Byte 1 = 00h

Byte 2 = FEh

Which basically equates to Start NDEF message, Message is zero length in size, End NDEF message.

---

I've not done any of this on iOS but is seems that iOS does offer low level read and write access of ISO15693 Tags

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfciso15693tag/3043817-writesingleblock